# Calling code from a single Javascript file instead of calling intepedent Javascript files

Tags: javascript, gdprconsentform, cookieconsent

I use a cookie consent policy banner from https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com which calls JS script files according the category they belong.

Fore example:
`<script type="text/plain" cookie-consent="tracking" src="google-analytics.js"></script>`
is called when users enable tracking cookies and
`<script type="text/plain" cookie-consent="targeting" src="google-adsense.js"></script>`
is called when users enable targeting cookies related to advertisement.

Is it possible to put all the relevant Javascript code in one file and instead of calling certain files according to the users' preferences to call the relevant functions in their place? Or is using separate files the only possible way of implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could put them all in one file if you wanted to and call the relevant functions, I would ask why they may be in separate files in the first place though normally the developer has done it for a reason.

Comment: 2 things:
1. Does GDPR allow the scripts to get loaded? Maybe in order to comply with the law the scripts should not load at all prior to making sure consent has been given.
2. If they are put on a single file on what event exactly should the functions get called? What event would that be that takes into account users' consent?

Comment: I can't speak about your specific situation because im not trying to do that, but all im simply saying is that you can technically do it. Any other considerations are up to you.